# Validate string # followed by digits but # increases after every occurance

Tags: regex, pcre

I have a string looks like this

```
#123##1234###2356####69
```

It starts with `#` and followed by any digits, every time the `#` appears, the number of `#` increases, first time 1, second time 2, etc.

It's similar to this regex, but since I don't know how long this pattern goes, so it's not very useful.

```
^#\d+##\d+###\d+$
```

I'm using PCRE regex engine, it allows recursion `(?R)` and conditions `(?(1)...)` etc.

Is there a regex to validate this pattern?

#### Valid

- `#123`
- `#12##235`
- `#1234##12###368`
- `#1234##12###368####22235#####723356`

#### Invalid

- `##123`
- `#123###456`
- `#123##456##789`

I tried [`^(?(1)(?|(#\1)|(#))\d+)+$`](https://regex101.com/r/UXaeYd/1/) but it doesn't seem to work at all

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this using [PCRE conditional sub-pattern matching](https://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html):

```sh
^(?:((?(1)\1)#)\d+)++$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/XO0g4H/3)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `(?:`: Start non-capture group

  - `(`: Start capture group #1

    - `(?(1)\1)`: `if/then/else` directive that means match back-reference `\1` only if 1st capture group is available otherwise match null
    - `#`: Match an additional `#`
  - `)`: End capture group #1
  - `\d+`: Match 1+ digits
- `)++`: End non-capture group. Match 1+ of this non-capture group.
- `$`: End

Answer (score 5):

One option could be optionally matching a backreference to group 1 inside group 1 using a [possessive quantifier](https://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html) `\1?+#` adding # on every iteration.

```
^(?:(\1?+#)\d+)++$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `(\1?+#)\d+` Capture **group 1**, match an optional possessive backreference to what is already captured in group 1 and add matching a `#` followed by 1+ digits
- `)++` Close the non capture group and repeat 1+ times possessively
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rHwK6Q/1)

Answer (score 4):

I think you can use forward-referencing here:

```php
^(?:((?:\1(?!^)|^)#)\d+)+$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/C5RfVY/3).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:((?:\1(?!^)|^)#)\d+)+` - one or more occurrences of

  - `((?:\1(?!^)|^)#)` - Group 1 (the `\1` value):  start of string or an  occurrence of the Group 1 value if it is not at the string start position
  - `\d+`  - one or more digits
- `$` - end of string.

**NOTE**: This technique does not work in regex flavors that do not support forward referencing, like ECMAScript based flavors (e.g. JavaScript, VBA, C++ `std::regex`)

Answer (score 1):

Despite there are already  working answers, and inspired by Wiktor's answer, I came up this idea:

```
(?:(^#|#\1)\d+)+$
```

Which is also quite short and effective(also works for non pcre environment).

See the [test cases](https://regex101.com/r/xEA21u/1)

Comment: ++ for non PCRE option. You may want to add `^` to make it `^(?:(^#|#\1)\d+)+$` to improve efficiency.

Comment: Nice idea! Note that this does not work in JavaScript: `(?:(^#|#\1)\d+)+$` matches (`["#368", "#", index: 12, input: "#1234##12####368", groups: undefined]`)

Comment: @PeterThoeny I think it can be fixed by adding a `^` at the beginning

Comment: @HaoWu: Nope. On Chrome, `'#1234##12###368'.match(/(?:(^#|#\1)\d+)+$/)` returns `["#368", "#", index: 11, input: "#1234##12###368", groups: undefined]`, and `'#1234##12###368'.match(/^(?:(^#|#\1)\d+)+$/)` returns `null`

Comment: @PeterThoeny Man regex in JavaScript is so broken...

Comment: @HaoWu I explained it in my answer but in a very short: ECMAScript standard does not support forward referencing, it does not allow backreference inside its group.